# No priviligies to create table in custom database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, security, ddl, role

I'm using locally installed express edition of SQL server. `CURRENT_USER = dbo`, and I used win authentication. The database was successfully created this way:

```
CREATE DATABASE [online_banking]
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'online_banking', FILENAME = N'C:\...\online_banking.mdf' , 
  SIZE = 512000KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 30%)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'online_banking_log', FILENAME = N'C:\...\online_banking_log.ldf' , 
  SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 20GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

However creating table cause the error, that I don't have permission.

```
CREATE TABLE [online_banking].Customers 
     (
      customer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
      customer_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT PK_cust_id
               PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (customer_id)
               WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
      )
;
```

What is wrong here?

P.S. Table can be created this way:  `CREATE TABLE Customers ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a table in a schema called `online_banking`. In some platforms a schema and a database are synonymous, but in SQL Server, a schema is a container inside a database.

> Instance > Database > Schema > Object

In order to create a table in the `online_banking` database, you need to use a three-part name or be in the context of that database. And you should [always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

```
USE online_banking;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.test1(i INT);
GO
```

Or:

```
CREATE TABLE online_banking.dbo.test1(i INT);
```